# Feature selection for Negative binomial regression

Tags: r, glm, feature-selection

I am trying to fit a negative binomial regression to count data, with 90 variables. Tried feature selection with GBM, LASSO and random forest. But when I fit the model using glm.nb from MASS, the coefficients are not statistically significant.

Is there a way to specify family = "negative binomial" for gbm or random forest?

Comment: Tree based methods are non-parametric and don't make distribution assumptions.

Comment: related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/361152/xgboost-poisson-objective-function-when-data-is-over-dispersed